# Updating table X on an Insert in table Y, with an SQLite trigger

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Elaboration: When an `INSERT` happens in `Table X`, the `count_updater` trigger should update a column in `Table Y` where the `_did` in both tables match. This should happen ***only*** for the freshly inserted row in Table X.

Pseudo-structures

```
Table X
 _id integer primarykey
 _did integer...
 ...
Table Y
 _did integer primarykey
 X_Count integer ...
...
```

The trigger script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER count_updater AFTER INSERT ON X 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Y SET X_Count = X_Count + 1 WHERE _did = NEW._did; 
END;
```

The trigger above fails. Kindly point out the mistake or help with the script as it ***should*** be. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What o you mean by "The trigger above fails"? It does not work as expected? You get an error message? In the second case, copy the error message for us to find out what happens.

Comment: Yes, @StephaneM, neither does it update the `X_Count` column in `table Y` nor does it throw any sort of error or log message.

Comment: Works for me. I'd guess you do not have a matching row in `Y`.

Comment: @CL., Confirmed that ***there's indeed a row*** in table Y that has the same _did. Agree with you below on both your statements. That's why this seems so baffling... please investigate.

Comment: Again, it [works for me](http://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-559b7e3de46b4ed844d4c8220d4c6e961111d250b190092164). Apparently, you've made a mistake in the code or the data you have not shown.

Comment: @CL., Yes, it works for me too, now. The mistake was using a deceptively similar column name in the UPDATE statement. Indeed there was no matching row in Table Y. Your fiddle was very helpful. Thank you!